Why there is only few multi channel high side drivers (like 8 and more) (example. TD62783AP)
I'm Currently working on a LED matrix project(5 row x 15 column) using some AVR with shift register (74HC595 to multiplexing outputs) and some low-side drivers (ULN2003A as switch to GND) and hight-side driver (TD62783AP as switch to VCC 12V). During research and buying components for this, I noticed that there is not so much of hight-side driver with multiple channels (like 6, 8 or more) - and started too wondering why?
Is my way for controlling multiple lines in LED matrix the wrong way, and I should use other parts or these parts are just not so popular / expensive / hard to produce & get (noticed some people buildings big transistor array in their projects).

Given the accuracy of your study of the current situation, and absent any specific advantages that may be present in some of what you found, this would cause me to prefer low-side current control and high-side switching. The reason is that it is very easy to arrange for a discrete switch (cheap.) Harder to arrange for a discrete high side current control. And if the emphasis is on the low side for both, then I'd take the more complex circuit in IC form (current control) and do the high side part in discrete devices (switching.)

High side switching requires lower-mobility P-type devices or N-type with more complicated drive circuitry.

There's another reason for that. The current control part has limited current. The switching part has to carry all of the possible loads that are enabled. And this, itself, may require a discrete device for dissipation reasons. Anyway, just offering all this as thoughts to encourage adding information into your question. Not trying to press any bright lines. So feel free to argue/respond with your own thoughts.

@periblepsis "low-side current control and high-side switching" can u please explain this part further, I'm quite new to whole transistor thing and try to understand as much as I can by doing some simple project. My idea is to build matrix using common 5mm red LED.

@Crax 5mm is great. What's the matrix size to start?

High side switching can be a bit awkward.
Either you use a PNP transistor (or PMOS when using FETs). They suffer from lower electron mobility than their NPN brethren, so they generally perform slightly worse (especially if you include price as a performance metric).
Alternatively, the high side switching element may be a NPN transistor, but now, when the switch is on, the base voltage inconveniently must be higher than the collector voltage. So you either need a second (higher) voltage rail, or locally generate it via e.g. a charge pump.

I will try to explain my idea more in this comment, the plan is to build LED matrix 5 row x 25 column using popular 5mm red LEDs.
Already soldered smaller LED matrix 5 row  x 3 column and now trying to connect them together and adding some control.
In every module I created, there are:
3 columns (one channel from 74HC595 & TD62783AP switching to VCC)
5 rows  (one channel from 74HC595 & ULN2003A switching to GND)
So in one column (common VCC) I have 5 x RED LED 5mm
If: 20mA
Vf: 2.0 To 2.2 V

Powered 12V (in case every LED is ON in any column).


PNPs are nearly on par; PMOS are solidly ~2.5x poorer though. MOSFETs are dominated by majority carriers, thus the lower hole mobility is a direct factor; bipolar transistors (of either polarity) depend on the presence of both charge carriers so are less sensitive (the performance ratio is more like ~10%); or something like that.

Understand that, what's available for sale, isn't what's possible, but also what's economically viable to market.
There are many kinds of high-side drivers available.  The most fully-featured are probably the wired-OR/ideal diode, hot-swap, load-switch and surge-stopper type products.
Mostly these are integrated circuits, with a single switch or driver inside, and including many features like multiple input or input-output sense (e.g. ideal diode), current sense, power or SOA calculation (analog multiplier required!), current limit, and soft-start, startup, fault and hold-off timers.
Typically an NMOS switch is used for performance and ease of integration.  Note that, for an NMOS to be fully on, high side, drain and source will be at whatever the supply/load voltage is, and gate needs to be, say, 5 to 15V above that.  Remember it's Vgs(on), not Vg (to ground).  To solve this, gate voltage is generated via onboard charge pump.
A charge pump is a nasty bit of circuitry to implement on an IC: capacitors are expensive to make (takes up a lot of die area), and tiny in value, and the voltage conversion or level shift ratio might be quite large, complicating the circuit further.  Even if the charge is pumped at high frequency, the small capacitors mean output current is very meager indeed.  Take TPS2491 for instance: it's rated to operate at 9 to 80V (100V abs. max.), and delivers 15-35µA (at 7V), with a limit of 12-16V, to the external transistor.  With such little gate current, turn-on tends to be very slow -- which is fine for a load-switch application, which might need soft-starting or current limiting anyway.
It's more difficult if you need, like, a PWM coil or LED driver: fast switching requires high gate turn-on current, and thus a large capacitor (already at Vgs(on)) to draw it from.  Such a driver might be able to obtain gate drive voltage from an external bootstrap capacitor, while switching, but still needs the expensive charge pump for 100% duty operation.
There are various ways such circuits could be integrated, and optimized -- perhaps we discard the current limiting and SOA protection features (or greatly simplify it, Vds sensing for example*), and perhaps we can charge-pump a single combined "over-supply" rail for the gate drivers, and, all the level-shift circuitry just goes in there easily enough, that doesn't cost much area.  But now we have a very specific product, and it's worth asking, what other markets and applications might be served by such a design (e.g. automotive load switches), and what needs/requirements do those have?
*Implication being, a reference voltage is compared to Vds(on) = Id * Rds(on), and limit/fault determined based on that.  Since Rds(on) varies with temperature and manufacture, this is a rather loose method, even if the Vref is very stable.  It's part of the reason LDOs tend to have loose current limit ratings: many are high-side (PMOS, or PNP, of which hFE also varies pretty broadly), so similar limitations apply as here too!
Or we could go in a different direction, making it a dumb driver, and the user is responsible for controlling switching for whatever purpose.  A charge-pump bootstrap gate driver like HIP4080 affords 100% duty cycle operation, but no logical or protective features whatsoever, just charge pump and level shift (in dual or quad, depending on your perspective -- it's an H-bridge driver, but if you only need the high side drivers, dual it would be).  With transistor attached, it could make a crude load driver -- but real loads often have a lot of considerations, and having to implement current limiting, surge protection, etc. externally may be more trouble than it's worth for that.
So it tends to be, load-driver products are one-off, or maybe dual, driving loads like relays, LEDs, coils, motors, etc.; often in automotive application, and have pretty wild supply ratings (like tolerating surge to ±40V or more, which makes the logic-input level shifting circuitry a bit more complicated).  And, how many loads, varies between modules in the car, so maybe a multi-part version isn't very important.  And, how much power the switch can handle (for fault, startup, surge, etc. reasons), may demand most of the die area be dedicated to the power transistor so that more than singles or doubles aren't really meaningful anyway (better to have more single components spread out over the board, to dissipate power more evenly).
So, it's not that there aren't solutions, or applications, for what you're looking for -- it's just that there aren't many, and other closely-related applications are more important (higher quantity), which have different priorities to yours, and thus different specs.
On the upside, since your application is very well constrained -- you don't have arbitrary loads plugged in, and perhaps don't even have to worry about connectors getting cross-wired or whatever (as can happen to automotive wiring harnesses, due to abrasion, impact, rodent damage, etc.) -- a simple high-side switching transistor, and probably nothing else, likely suffices.  It might be tedious, using individual transistors (or pairs; there are many affordable duals in SOT-23-6, SOT-363, etc.) and level shifting, but it's not awful overall.
Or, if you're using single LEDs here, the 12V supply is a huge waste; consider dropping to 3.3-5V with a buck regulator.  Then the high side can be driven directly from a 5V-tolerant MCU (open-drain mode) or 5V-powered GPIO (certain Arduinos).
You might also consider using a matrix controller like HT16K33, or TM1640 and clones (AIP1640 etc.). Maybe you don't need the fuller feature set of the former (digit dimming, etc.), maybe you don't want to use I2C, that's fine.
